# Elasticsearch: sorted nested array

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to configure the mapping of an index, or the discover view of this in index in a way that an array inside the documents is / will be sorted?

Background: I have a es index with documents containing an array:
This array is updated from time to time with new entries (objects containing a timestamp), and I would like this arrays to be sorted according to the timestamp inside the objects.

Answer (score 1):

If your field is define as `nested` type then you can use `inner_hits` to sort the array of object. it will return the sorted object array inside `inner_hits` for each document.

You can define field as `nested` like below:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "openTimes": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "date": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let consider below is your sample data:

```json
{"index": { } }
{ "name": "second on 6th (3rd on the 5th)", "openTimes": [ { "date": "2018-12-05T12:00:00" ,"name":"abc"}, { "date": "2018-12-06T11:00:00","name":"xyz" }] }
{"index": { } }
{ "name": "third on 6th (1st on the 5th)", "openTimes": [ {"date": "2018-12-05T10:00:00","name":"abc"}, { "date": "2018-12-06T12:00:00","name":"xyz" }] }
{"index": { } }
{ "name": "first on the 6th (2nd on the 5th)", "openTimes": [ {"date": "2018-12-05T11:00:00","name":"abc" }, { "date": "2018-12-06T10:00:00","name":"xyz" }] }
```

Below is **Query**:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "openTimes",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "sort": {
           "openTimes.date": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample Response:

```json
{
        "_index" : "nested-listings",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "u0fw338BMCbs63yKkqi0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "second on 6th (3rd on the 5th)",
          "openTimes" : [
            {
              "date" : "2018-12-05T12:00:00",
              "name" : "abc"
            },
            {
              "date" : "2018-12-06T11:00:00",
              "name" : "xyz"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "openTimes" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "nested-listings",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "u0fw338BMCbs63yKkqi0",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "openTimes",
                    "offset" : 1
                  },
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "date" : "2018-12-06T11:00:00",
                    "name" : "xyz"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1544094000000
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "nested-listings",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "u0fw338BMCbs63yKkqi0",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "openTimes",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "date" : "2018-12-05T12:00:00",
                    "name" : "abc"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    1544011200000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```